# Get Insert/Delete/Update operations with data from the transaction log

Tags: sql-server, audit

Can anyone please provide a script using `fn_dblog` to find Insert/Delete/Update operations with data (like Change Data Capture) that are made to the SQL Server from transaction log.

I can't enable [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server#Capture) since I am using SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition.

[Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server#Tracking) is not suitable since I need before and after values.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone please explain the script to find Insert/Delete/Update operations with data (like cdc) that are made to the sql server from transaction log.

Free ones of this would be a program and they are generally paid for. There are no free ones that I know of. Additionally the SQL Server Transaction Log is *not* documented as it is for internal use only.

> I cant enable cdc since I am using SQL server 2012 standard edition.

Then either change your edition or go without. You can write your own tracking using triggers, but it's going to make your application run extremely slow.

You really need to look into items that do this, Golden Gate, CDC, CT, etc., and go from there. If you can't spend any money then you need to make a business justification case for it and if still nothing, you can write it [using triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962398/creating-audit-triggers-in-sql-server). Note that using triggers is still spending money on development... so either way money is being used.